# using w3.css my accordion works, but text doesn't wrap

Tags: javascript, html, accordion, w3.css

My code below is part of a small website using w3.css
The accordion opens OK, and the text within the "hide" sections wraps properly.
But the text beginning "JOB TITLE" and the other beginning "Job Description:" both fail to wrap, that's to say they disappear off the right-hand edge of the viewport.
The desired behavior is that all text should wrap when viewed on a narrow viewport.

```html
<button onclick="myFunction('uid22222')" class="w3-button w3-left-align job_title">JOB TITLE HERE - WHICH MIGHT BE VERY AND VERY AND VERY AND VERY LONGGGGGG SO NEEDS TO WRAP WHEN VIEWED IN A NARROW VIEWPORT LIKE A PHONE SCREEN

    <div class="job_briefly">Job Description: Some text here which briefly describes the vacancy and which needs to wrap when viewed in a narrow viewport, which happens ok when viewing the "hide" text below..<br>And some more text.</button>

    <div id="uid22222" class="w3-hide job_hidden">
      Location details.
      <br><b>Organisation Name</b>
      <br>Pay & Hours &/or Benefits.
      <br>Apply on or before xxx date.</div>

    <script>
   function myFunction(id) {
   var x = document.getElementById(id);
   if (x.className.indexOf("w3-show") == -1) {
     x.className += " w3-show";
   } else {
     x.className = x.className.replace(" w3-show", "");
   }
   }
   </script>
```

Comment: "The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and ***the shortest code necessary*** to reproduce the problem."

Comment: I have shortened the code, and added in the javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "w3-button" you can use "w3-card" for example.